# In a triangle ABC with medians $AE$, $BF$, $CD$, we have $\overrightarrow{AE}+\overrightarrow{BF}+\overrightarrow{CD}=0$ with Synthetic Geometry?

Tags: synthetic-geometry

I am trying to set up Mathematica Synthetic Geometry stuff to prove the following:

> Given a triangle ABC with medians $AE$, $BF$, $CD$. Show that we have $\overrightarrow{AE}+\overrightarrow{BF}+\overrightarrow{CD}=0$.

I wrote a piece of code I thought would be useful for this but FindGeometricConjectures won't yield anything useful. How can I create a scene where such conclusion can appear? I know that this can be done much more elementary (without Mathematica's Synthetic Geometry) but I want to learn about Synthetic Geometry.

```
G = RandomInstance[GeometricScene[
    {a, b, c, d, e, f},
    {
     d == Midpoint[{a, b}],
     e == Midpoint[{b, c}],
     f == Midpoint[{c, a}],
     Triangle[{a, b, c}],
     Line[{a, e}],
     Line[{b, f}],
     Line[{c, d}]
     }
    ]];
FindGeometricConjectures[G]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or prove directly.(This proof also work for 3-dimension or n-dimension)

```
Clear[n, a, b, c, d, e, f];
n = 2;
d = Mean[{a, b}];
e = Mean[{b, c}];
f = Mean[{c, a}];
Reduce[(d - c) + (e - a) + (f - b) == 
  0, {a, b, c, d, e, f} ∈ Vectors[n]]
```

> `True`.

Answer (score 2):

```
G = RandomInstance[
   GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, {d == Midpoint[{a, b}], 
     e == Midpoint[{b, c}], f == Midpoint[{c, a}], 
     Triangle[{a, b, c}], Line[{a, e}], Line[{b, f}], Line[{c, d}]}]];
```

Not entirely satisfactorily but using the points in `G`:

```
Chop@((d - c) + (f - b) + (e - a) /. G["Points"] ) == {0, 0}
```

> True

Comment: Interesting that there are other ways of using this, I thought that we could only use this by combining GeometricScene and FindGeometricConjectures. Is there a way to make FindGeometricConjectures yield this conclusion or at least something equivalent to it?

Comment: Perhaps there is, but I don't know how to use vectors with a `GeometricScene`.